# c# code to extract my name from web

Tags: c#-4.0

How can I write code to search my name 'teera' in the entire website www.test.com  when found copy url to text fire

Comment: By entire web site you mean crawling all the links or just the home page?

Answer (score 1):

I would use Google to search the website. Crawling it manually would be much more complicated.

There are Google .NET libraries like [Linq to Google](http://glinq.codeplex.com/).